# How I can connect my device with input 15-20V to my power bank

Tags: voltage, dc, dc-dc-converter, powerbanks

I have a power bank from baseus 65w, which can be output 20V ~3.25A. That brick successfully charge my laptop with 20V via USB-C. I want to connect my another device which input: 15-20V 1A and have DC 5.5 connector. I found USB to DC5.5 cable, and when I trying to connect, my power bank always do 5v.

How I can force my power bank to connect my device. Need I dc-dc step up/down convertor? Thx

Comment: TL/DR : No. No, your other device needs to negotiate the required output via USB. It can't do that through a barrel jack. Step-up? Read the powerbank spec for 5V output : if it can't do 5V 3-4A without negotiation, there isn't enough current for the step-up.

Comment: @BrianDrummond ok, how I can get 20V from this power bank in the end? How my laptop can charge with this voltage? Sorry for my stupid questions

Comment: *Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design.* - without design details or detailed specifications of your power bank this cannot be answered. Hence, if you had those specs you'd be able to answer it yourself. Voting to close.

Comment: Ok, I think, I found solution, I need usb-c cable to dc with trigger PD 20V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB by default is 5V, all devices can be sure they will get that voltage at the beginning. With USBC and USB-PD, there is a negotiation protocol for the load and source to agree on a new voltage. Thus you need a PD trigger and then set it to 20V. USB-PD is fairly complex and so i would suggest you get a prebuilt usb-pd trigger. [Video of GreatScott using a USB-PD trigger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQLrZA5RMjQ) [Aliexpress listing for a USB-PD trigger board](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000139809599.html?aff_fsk=_dZA5cwi&aff_platform=portals-search&sk=_dZA5cwi&aff_trace_key=d99c5c4b6c4849d38678f9900d21437a-1613310374640-01290-_dZA5cwi&terminal_id=08c6d96417814f25901cf6bd2b61c43b&tmLog=new_Detail) There are numerous boards like that on aliexpress.

Comment: Thx, that what I need!